# paypal Adaptive Payments button

Tags: paypal, chained-payments

I'm looking to create simple Paypal button, where clicking on the button will transfer the money to 2 different accounts(e.g. the button payment = $10(pre defined) and $2 goes to account 1, and $8 goes to account 2.

What is the easiest way to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you would need is either our product chained payment or parallel payment (depending if you want to receive the original transaction first or split it directly).
You will find some information on that page and hope it will help you in your decision : https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/

Regards,
Florian